# How to automatically create and assign ticket in trac to responsible developer if build failes

Tags: jenkins, trac

I'm searching for a possibility to automatically create a new ticket in trac in case of a build failure. The problem is, that the ticket has to be assigned to the person who broke the build.
I tried the [TicketToTracScript](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketToTracScript) to create a ticket, but I don't know how to get the responsible person for the ticket.

Comment: A bit more information would be helpful. I.e. is the author on check-in to the repository identical to Trac username?

Comment: I don't know Jenkins at all. Do you know afterwards, what revision failed to build? If Yes, it boils down to finding revision's author/committer in the repository, right? Beware: Assuming, that the committer broke the build, will lead to undesired effects: Until a broken source has been fixed, any committer will get a ticket assigned to him/her, while only the first ticket might be a legitimate accuse.

Comment: for git this command will return author of current commit
`git log -n 1 --format="%aN"`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the responsible person for the ticket"?

If you mean the account responsible for filing the ticket, then I recommend creating a separate Trac user account for your auto-build system.  This account would only be used by scripts that auto-file tickets.  This is typically a much easier route to take than trying to re-use someone's developer account.

If you mean the person to whom the ticket should be assigned, then I'm afraid that there's no easy answer.  Determining who is responsible for breaking a build is usually very difficult to automate based solely on the build results.

If your build output gives you a line number for the offense that caused the failure, you can use a feature like [`svn blame`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html) (if your version control system has something similar) to see who was the last person to change that line.  That may not actually be the person who broke the build, however, but it does give you a start.  I have seen some systems that list everyone who modified the offending file since the last build on the ticket in the "CC" field, and list the last person to change that line as the owner.  That will at least cause the issue to be investigated, and the ticket can be re-assigned if needed.

The only true way to know who broke the build is to attempt to build intermediate revisions until you discover the commit that caused the problem.  Tools like [`git bisect`](http://book.git-scm.com/5_finding_issues_-_git_bisect.html) are useful for this, if your revision control system provides something analagous.  This is of course completely dependent on the length of time it takes to do a full build.  If you have a large code base that takes 45 minutes to build, then this would probably take far too much time to be practical.  If your project is, say, broken up into individual components that can be built separately, then you can test-build only the component that failed and quickly identify the offending commit.